# replace domain name from string into links php

Tags: php, regex

I am creating a function in PHP able to link an url (type `google.com` only) within an string. the type of url is `google.com` whitout protocols `http`, `https`, etc or `www`; just like `facebook.com` or `twitter.com.uk`

I did create the next function but it fails when the url is next to () or another special character.

```
 function linkify($tring){
 $regex="/[^\W ]+[^\s]+[.]+[^\" ]+[^\W ]+/i";

  return preg_replace("$regex", "<a href=\"http://\\0\" TARGET=_BLANK>\\0</a>",$string);

 return $string;
  }
```

for example the function fails (it consider the parenthesis part of the link):

```
   google.com)sd   
   p(google.com
   mn[google.com
  [google.com]td
  google.com}er
```

Comment: This is going to be virtually impossible since `.without` could well *be* a TLD now - it isn't (yet) but the registry is open for practically anything to be registered. You're going to have to match *any* `abc.xyz` type string and parse it to see if it's a valid domain - you could go with robert's suggestion below and check it with `checkdnsrr()` but that is going to slow the page load down considerably if there are many strings to check... or you're going to have to accept that you'll get some duff links.

Comment: it will delay it but won't be taking more cpu usage , also i think that the DNSs are cached and so it won't check the url over and over again , so if this will happen when storing the strings into database it will be reasonable to check all of them , but if it's when retrieving from the database it will delay it alot

Comment: Thanks, What about a regex which limits the number of characters after the periods used by default in the domain, for example (limits three characters after the first and second period of a domain this type `domain.xyz.mnp` ). whit this I think it would be a good start.

Comment: It is within a php string `$string=" visit  domain.xyz ,it has an awesome blog  blog.domain.xyz, here in another language blog.domain.xyz.pq"`

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp needs to take care of the domain extension.
On wikipedia you can find this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domains

And build you regexp with it.

Comment: If I do this, I think I would have to make a regex usign several times this separator `|` with the extension names, It would be better if after the dots allows something like this  `[A-Za-z]{2,4}+[A-Za-z]{2,4}`

Comment: You can and you cannot : with new domain extension (check this https://iwantmyname.com/domains/new-gtld-domain-extensions ), there are domain extension length up to several characters, so your pattern will match pretty much any word.
However with all method there are some cases you cannot handle, ex :
"I wish I lived there.Paris is beautiful" . Well, ".paris" is a valid domain extension, both methods will match.
Remember it's better to leave the option to the user than enable a broken feature trying to be smart.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [checkdnsrr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) to see if it's a link or just text

or you can use regex like that `[^\s]+[.][^\" ]*(test.com|domain.com)` this will allow replace only the links with test.com ,domain.com or their subdomains

Comment: I tried that but the list is huge. The optimal would be recognize any type of domain using general regex only?

Comment: you need to replace only specific domains or any valid domain ?

Comment: I cant have control what users post. And the urls they post  have to be replaced by links.

Comment: so you have two options now , 1 is to use the `checkdnsrr` to make sure this link is exist , two you use all the top level domains from the page `JesusTheHun` provided and use them with my regexp to check them

Comment: btw the list is very big and checking all the urls with that BIG regexp will take alot of time i think so i'd recommended that you use the `checkdnsrr` or use small set of top level domains like org com net only and leave the others